# How to get stylesheet URLs using php dom xpath or regex?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am building my custom library for merging all screen css stylesheets but I am not sure how to get stylesheets for the media type `screen` only. For example:

```
<!-- This should be fetched -->
<link href="http://www.domain.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- This should be fetched -->
<link href="http://www.domain.com/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style type="text/css" media="all">
  <!-- This should be fetched -->
  @import url("http://static.php.net/www.php.net/styles/phpnet.css");
</style>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
   <!-- This should be fetched -->
  @import url("http://static.php.net/www.php.net/styles/site.css");
</style>

<style type="text/css" media="print">
  <!-- This should NOT be fetched since it is media type print -->
  @import url("http://static.php.net/www.php.net/styles/print.css");
</style>
```

Given above string, I just want to extract `href` and `url` values. I don't know how to go about with that. Although I did try:

```
preg_match_all("/(url\([\'\"]?)([^\"\'\)]+)([\"\']?\))/", $html, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

But it doesn't return it.

Any solution with php dom, xpath or regex to achieve that ?

Comment: you will want to parse the dom. this might make it easier for you: http://code.google.com/p/ganon/ (disclaimer: I've never used it myself, but looks like it will support what you need)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the working code !
I have  created a codepad pastebin also for you: http://codepad.org/WQzcO3k3

```
<?php

$inputString = '<!-- This should be fetched -->
<link href="http://www.domain.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- This should be fetched -->
<link href="http://www.domain.com/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style type="text/css" media="all">
  <!-- This should be fetched -->
  @import url("http://static.php.net/www.php.net/styles/phpnet.css");
</style>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
   <!-- This should be fetched -->
  @import url("http://static.php.net/www.php.net/styles/site.css");
</style>

<style type="text/css" media="print">
  <!-- This should NOT be fetched since it is media type print -->
  @import url("http://static.php.net/www.php.net/styles/print.css");
</style>';
$outputUrls = array();

@$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($inputString);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc); // just to make xpath more simple

$linksOrStyles = $xml->xpath('//*[@rel="stylesheet" or @media="all" or @media="screen"]');     


//print_r($linksOrStyles);

foreach ($linksOrStyles as $linkOrStyleSimpleXMLElementObj)
{
    if ($linkOrStyleSimpleXMLElementObj->xpath('@href') != false) {
      $outputUrls[] = $linkOrStyleSimpleXMLElementObj['href'] . '';
    } else {
        //get the 'url' value.
        $httpStart = strpos($linkOrStyleSimpleXMLElementObj.'', 'http://');
        $httpEnd = strpos($linkOrStyleSimpleXMLElementObj.'', '"', $httpStart);
        $outputUrls[] = substr($linkOrStyleSimpleXMLElementObj.'', $httpStart, ($httpEnd - $httpStart));
        //NOTE:Use preg_match only to get URL. i had to use strpos here 
        //since codepad.org doesnt suport preg
        /*
        preg_match(
            "#((http|https|ftp)://(\S*?\.\S*?))(\s|\;|\)|\]|\[|\{|\}|,|\"|'|:|\<|$|\.\s)#ie",
            ' ' . $linkOrStyleSimpleXMLElementObj,
            $matches
        );
        print_r($matches);
        $outputUrls[] = $matches[0];
        */
    }
}

echo 'Output Url list: ';
print_r($outputUrls);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dev01 for accceptance